# Solving differential recurrence equations

Tags: recurrence-relations, differential

I played around trying to make an equation describing Fibonacci numbers and ended up finding out that what I'd created was something called a recurrence equation:

$f(x)=f(x-1)+f(x-2)$

($f(x)$ is equal to the sum of the function value to the last two previous integer $x$-values's )

I looked it up and found out that this type of recurrence equation can be solved analytically (A solution function exists).

My question goes: Can this type of equation be solved if it contains one or more of the functions derivatives?
E.g.: $f(x)=f'(x-1)+f(x-2)$

I can't see why it should be impossible, but I'm unable to find any information on Google and my math teacher doesn't know anything about recurrence equations. Is there a reason why the type of equation (recurrence differential equations) doesn't seem to exist?

Comment: If your derivative is on $f(x)$ instead of $f(x-1)$, then it is a [delayed differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_differential_equation). Not sure about the name for your example.

Comment: Couldn't I just rewrite the equation:
f(x)=f'(x−1)+f(x−2)
f(x+1)=f'(x)+f(x−1)
-f'(x)=+f(x−1)-f(x+1)
f'(x)=-f(x−1)+f(x+1)
And have a DDE?